# Kubernetes Authentication issue

Tags: kubernetes

I started looking at different ways of using authentication on kubernetes. Of course, I started with the simplest option, static password file. Basically, I created a file named users.csv with the following content:

```
mauro,maurosil,maurosil123,group_mauro
```

When I start minikube using this file, it hangs at the cluster components (starting cluster components). The command I use is:

minikube --extra-config=apiserver.Authentication.PasswordFile.BasicAuthFile=~/temp/users.csv start

After a while (~ 10 minutes), the minikube start command fails with the following error message:

```
E0523 10:23:57.391692   30932 util.go:151] Error uploading error message: : Post https://clouderrorreporting.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/k8s-minikube/events:report?key=AIzaSyACUwzG0dEPcl-eOgpDKnyKoUFgHdfoFuA: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

I can see that there are several errors on the log (minikube logs):

```
ay 23 09:47:32 minikube kubelet[3301]: E0523 09:47:32.473157    3301 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/config/apiserver.go:47: Failed to list *v1.Pod: Get https://192.168.99.100:8443/api/v1/pods?fieldSelector=spec.nodeName%3Dminikube&limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 192.168.99.100:8443: getsockopt: connection refused
May 23 09:47:33 minikube kubelet[3301]: E0523 09:47:33.414460    3301 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go:460: Failed to list *v1.Node: Get https://192.168.99.100:8443/api/v1/nodes?fieldSelector=metadata.name%3Dminikube&limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 192.168.99.100:8443: getsockopt: connection refused
May 23 09:47:33 minikube kubelet[3301]: E0523 09:47:33.470604    3301 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go:451: Failed to list *v1.Service: Get https://192.168.99.100:8443/api/v1/services?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 192.168.99.100:8443: getsockopt: connection refused
May 23 09:47:33 minikube kubelet[3301]: E0523 09:47:33.474548    3301 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/config/apiserver.go:47: Failed to list *v1.Pod: Get https://192.168.99.100:8443/api/v1/pods?fieldSelector=spec.nodeName%3Dminikube&limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 192.168.99.100:8443: getsockopt: connection refused
May 23 09:47:34 minikube kubelet[3301]: I0523 09:47:34.086654    3301 kubelet_node_status.go:271] Setting node annotation to enable volume controller attach/detach
May 23 09:47:34 minikube kubelet[3301]: I0523 09:47:34.090697    3301 kubelet_node_status.go:82] Attempting to register node minikube
May 23 09:47:34 minikube kubelet[3301]: E0523 09:47:34.091108    3301 kubelet_node_status.go:106] Unable to register node "minikube" with API server: Post https://192.168.99.100:8443/api/v1/nodes: dial tcp 192.168.99.100:8443: getsockopt: connection refused
May 23 09:47:34 minikube kubelet[3301]: E0523 09:47:34.370484    3301 event.go:209] Unable to write event: 'Patch https://192.168.99.100:8443/api/v1/namespaces/default/events/minikube.15313c5b8cf5913c: dial tcp 192.168.99.100:8443: getsockopt: connection refused' (may retry after sleeping)
May 23 09:47:34 minikube kubelet[3301]: E0523 09:47:34.419833    3301 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go:460: Failed to list *v1.Node: Get https://192.168.99.100:8443/api/v1/nodes?fieldSelector=metadata.name%3Dminikube&limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 192.168.99.100:8443: getsockopt: connection refused
May 23 09:47:34 minikube kubelet[3301]: E0523 09:47:34.472826    3301 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go:451: Failed to list *v1.Service: Get https://192.168.99.100:8443/api/v1/services?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 192.168.99.100:8443: getsockopt: connection refused
May 23 09:47:34 minikube kubelet[3301]: E0523 09:47:34.479619    3301 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/config/apiserver.go:47: Failed to list *v1.Pod: Get https://192.168.99.100:8443/api/v1/pods?fieldSelector=spec.nodeName%3Dminikube&limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 192.168.99.100:8443: getsockopt: connection refused
```

I also logged in the minikube VM (minikube ssh) and I noticed that the apiserver docker container is down. Looking at the logs of this container I see the following error:

```
error: unknown flag: --Authentication.PasswordFile.BasicAuthFile
```

Therefore, I changed my command to something like:

```
minikube start --extra-config=apiserver.basic-auth-file=~/temp/users.csv
```

It failed again but now the container shows a different error. The error is no longer related to invalid flag. Instead, it complains that the file not found (no such file or directory). I also tried to specify a file on the minikube vm (/var/lib/localkube) but I had the same issue.

The minikube version is:

```
minikube version: v0.26.0
```

When I start minikube without considering the authentication, it works fine. Are there any other steps that I need to do?

Mauro

Answer (score 0):

You will need to mount the file into the docker container that runs apiserver. Pls see a hack that worked: https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/1898#issuecomment-402714802